# Flyway quarkus extension get "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus" when executing test

Tags: jdbc, datasource, flyway, quarkus

When execute *mvnw test* in my project using Flyway quarkus extension with version 1.13.2_Final, it produces the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:

Unable to obtain connection from database: Error General : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-197]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : HY000
Error Code : 50000
Message    : Error General : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-197]

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
Error General : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-197]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have the following configuration for datasource and flyware en **test** profile.

```
"%test":
  quarkus:
    datasource:
      db-kind: h2
      jdbc:
        credentials-provider: my-bbdd-credentials-provider
        driver: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:test;MODE=Oracle
        max-size: 13
    flyway:
      locations: db/migration-test
      schemas: PUBLIC
      baseline-on-migrate: true
      migrate-at-start: true
```

I think Quarkus flyway extension isn't using the class that implements *credential-provider*. This class decrypts the user's password from other property. This class works well when using *credential-provider* with *agroal* and *hibernate-orm-panache* extensions.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bug, can you open an issue?

Comment: Ok. I'll prepare a example project and I´ll open an issue

Comment: thanks for your help. It looks an issue with mode=Oracle parameter